# VBA ADODB wierd value results from query

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

I`m using ADODB in VBA Excel to connect to an existing DBF database to parse the information and generate a report. My SQL statements might not be the best, but they seemed to work. I however encountered a weird problem with my query results, and upon investigation noticed that in some rear cases my query returns false data. My original SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT nofac, 
       class, 
       branch, 
       Iif(dental = true, pedental + pbdental, NULL)  AS prim1, 
       Iif(dental2 = true, pedental + pbdental, NULL) AS prim2, 
       Iif(dental3 = true, pedental + pbdental, NULL) AS prim3, 
       Iif(dental4 = true, pedental + pbdental, NULL) AS prim4, 
       pxdental                                       AS tax, 
       social_ins 
FROM   base.dbf 
WHERE  nofac BETWEEN 123456 AND 123458
```

base.dbf contains around 400k records, 100 would match the nofac=123456.
PEDENTAL and PBDENTAL holds the rate amount while the dental though dental4 indicates the type of rate it is (boolean value).

The problem I noticed is that the total of prim1+prim2+prim3+prim4 would be greater then the total of all PEDENTAL+PBDENTAL for the record set. Which should be impossible.

I re-run my SQL statement to see what was causing the corruption of data and noticed that in some cases, around 5% of the time the dental, dental2 would both return true and sometimes all 4 would return true.

```
SELECT nofac, 
       class, 
       branch, 
       dental, 
       dental2, 
       dental3, 
       dental4, 
       social_ins 
FROM   histemp.dbf 
WHERE  nofac = 123456
```

1. FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE
2. TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
3. FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE

However, this is where I stop understanding what is going on, If i look at raw data for the records that are returning multiple trues, i find that only one of the 4 values is set to true. Also, if i reran my statement adding a secondary where clause to isolate the corrupted record, the result is how it should be, with only a single true.

For example THE the line 3 in the above example would appear as when I query just that single line:

. FALSE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE

Does anyone have an idea as to what I am doing wrong, or what is going on?

Comment: Create a copy from database, run repair command on it (under Foxpro? I misread DBF as MDB, sorry), check again. I have seen similar results when database is corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. it`s actually a dBase database. I recreated the index and used a repair tool that I downloaded, since I could not find a dBase command to do that, but it did not help. I also tried resetting the values manually for the effected records, also to no avail.  I had a an older backup of the file from couple of month ago, but unfortunately it does the same thing

Comment: I was not able to figure out why this was happening, mostly as Arvo mentioned caused by a corruption, I was however able to find a work around that can be applied in my case, as I have the rate type information duplicated in another recordset that I can reference.